# PHP json_decode not display all data in array

Tags: php, json

I'm currently access to an json API. I get response json data like this one.

```
{
"fileName":null,
"fileUrl":[  
   "U2FsdGVkX1-uM6l4RxCWpIiXiCglblQ45V61bTVvuRC2H3ru72DjM0I337iegtL0eG7-t_H_CEeMrc3vopGkVA",
   "U2FsdGVkX19AX2GGMh_dy71pYYNjgI5Dp1doC58zYqbZbjz02KWdVn5BXjiLcOqjLcgHgKFiOvLQXbRMTzVMJUATPQGh-zMmWaUtUJ0gveLvKOaX3FkM33ZrblwISSBZeocZHxIVxOR1jFpUf9HmuQ",
   "U2FsdGVkX1_XwHvpVBapqhs4fw-6SlUcF8U7rXFxdWTBWeKU7mxQwi1rh9Hor4wPLhQub_qFIprhH59iM90CGsiomMuRmv6cfFBrDzIUkyIEUf83-uBin8L6SWGoyZrQpB6jdAt_elGnS3lYp-TUGg",
   "U2FsdGVkX1-dlLo5wNZpACpERA7aJz-hzegQZ7VGl_uSn9fle1ykAud-ax2kqVhYsmDMJoYbogX9--WFFhAkXCoulHX2wGeD1_N1uvoZvd6-B-4EBmwguntVKHZo3BExZCz0OmRG65gBBXCcV7M10g",
   "U2FsdGVkX1-11v5vUHoO1Yx7Pbsz1OgR4PkmFMHBcw2YO6gQanKg6NL6jLUVF1AqOK5nmTAazur7SZtjIRatJ3_NVR7Q4ya7rZbkXdEIslJKp6hpkgASbJ1hUAWKoNgjoxUEs2FclnQyiTDHntlCUQ"
],
"categoryId":"1110"
}
```

When I'm trying to decode json to get all fileUrl. It's only display the first data in fileUrl[0]. In this case is *U2FsdGVkX1-uM6l4RxCWpIiXiCglblQ45V61bTVvuRC2H3ru72DjM0I337iegtL0eG7-t_H_CEeMrc3vopGkVA*
I think it should have object or array to foreach, not string. How to get all fileUrl in that array?

Here is my code

```
$fileUrl = json_decode($jsonData)->fileUrl; 
foreach ($fileUrl as $url) {
 print_r($url);
}
```

Comment: code you tried????

Comment: Please share your code that used to decode.

Comment: $fileUrl = json_decode($jsonData)->fileUrl;
foreach ($fileUrl as $url) {
 print_r($url);
}

Comment: you will get all urls as an object in fileUrl variable and if you pass true in json_decode function you will get array of it as per your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in following way

```
$fileUrls = json_decode($jsonData, true)['fileUrl'];

foreach($fileUrls as $url) {
  echo $url."\n\n";
}
```

working example [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5583e13f9e3b8c1c048e18f20b1d2f2a010cd41e)

Comment: I've made a change and it works like a charm. Thank you!
https://notepad.pw/c7zc31xw

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
$json = '{"fileName":null,"fileUrl":["U2FsdGVkX1-uM6l4RxCWpIiXiCglblQ45V61bTVvuRC2H3ru72DjM0I337iegtL0eG7-t_H_CEeMrc3vopGkVA","U2FsdGVkX19AX2GGMh_dy71pYYNjgI5Dp1doC58zYqbZbjz02KWdVn5BXjiLcOqjLcgHgKFiOvLQXbRMTzVMJUATPQGh-zMmWaUtUJ0gveLvKOaX3FkM33ZrblwISSBZeocZHxIVxOR1jFpUf9HmuQ","U2FsdGVkX1_XwHvpVBapqhs4fw-6SlUcF8U7rXFxdWTBWeKU7mxQwi1rh9Hor4wPLhQub_qFIprhH59iM90CGsiomMuRmv6cfFBrDzIUkyIEUf83-uBin8L6SWGoyZrQpB6jdAt_elGnS3lYp-TUGg","U2FsdGVkX1-dlLo5wNZpACpERA7aJz-hzegQZ7VGl_uSn9fle1ykAud-ax2kqVhYsmDMJoYbogX9--WFFhAkXCoulHX2wGeD1_N1uvoZvd6-B-4EBmwguntVKHZo3BExZCz0OmRG65gBBXCcV7M10g","U2FsdGVkX1-11v5vUHoO1Yx7Pbsz1OgR4PkmFMHBcw2YO6gQanKg6NL6jLUVF1AqOK5nmTAazur7SZtjIRatJ3_NVR7Q4ya7rZbkXdEIslJKp6hpkgASbJ1hUAWKoNgjoxUEs2FclnQyiTDHntlCUQ"],"categoryId":"1110"}';

$jsonObj = json_decode($json);

echo $jsonObj->fileUrl[0];
```